# MPLAB C18 compiler float-point type some questions

Tags: microchip, mplab

The [MPLAB® C18 C Compiler User’s Guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_C18_Users_Guide_51288c.pdf)
says that float type is different from IEEE745.

[image: the doc words]

However, in the program it build the float is still of IEEE745 type.

[image]
The float is 0x302e0000 in program memory, which is IEEE745 type as opposed to what the documentation says.

Why is this the case?

Comment: fix:The float is 0x302e0000----->the result is 0x3e200000 (0.15625f )